# Vagrant Installation in Debian Os

Tags: linux, rubygems, debian, vagrant, virtualbox

I have been trying to install and set up vagrant in my local machine which runs on debian OS for PHP project.
As mentioned in the link https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads, I followed all the setups listed for installing Virtual Box initially. After successful installation I tried installing Vagrant by downloading it from official website. Once all installation is done, I create a directory called website cd into it and gave the command

```
Vagrant init
```

For vagrant initialization. But vagrant returns me the following error. How to resolve this?

```
Vagrant experienced a version conflict with some installed plugins!
This usually happens if you recently upgraded Vagrant. As part of the
upgrade process, some existing plugins are no longer compatible with
this version of Vagrant. The recommended way to fix this is to remove
your existing plugins and reinstall them one-by-one. To remove all
plugins:

rm -r ~/.vagrant.d/plugins.json ~/.vagrant.d/gems

Note if you have an alternate VAGRANT_HOME environmental variable
set, the folders above will be in that directory rather than your
user's home directory.

The error message is shown below:

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rest-client":
In Gemfile:
vagrant (= 1.7.0) ruby depends on
  rest-client (~> 1.7) ruby

vagrant-share (>= 0) ruby depends on
  rest-client (1.6.8)
```

Comment: Did you upgrade from an older version to 1.7.x ? What is the exact version you have installed/upgraded ?

Comment: Seems to be an issue with Vagrant 1.7.x , you can follow the GitHub thread : https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/4921